# Select trace(s) for R plotly graph based on checkboxinput for shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, reactive

I have a plotly graph with many lines I added manually with add_trace. I would like to be able to select which lines appear on the graph by selecting checkboxes. I'd also like to be able to have the checkboxes represent several variables. For example, checking the checkbox called "Choice A" returns the lines for varone and vartwo.

I feel like I've tried everything but haven't had any luck. I tried out various reactive functions, but couldn't get them to work, since my variables are in columns, and each trace selects an individual column, so I didn't include reactivity in the code below because I can't get it to work. Help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinythemes)

 mydataset <-data.frame( date  = c("12/01/2016", "12/02/2016",  "12/03/2016"),
              varone = c(60, 65, 80),
              vartwo = c(90, 45, 100),
              varthree = c(15, 120,201))


 ui <- shinyUI(
  navbarPage(theme=shinytheme("journal"), "My Dashboard",
  tabPanel("Data",
    fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
        column(2, dateRangeInput("daterange1", label = h5("Date Range:"),
                                 start = "2001-01-01",
                                 end   = "2010-12-31"),
               br(),
               checkboxGroupInput("mydataset", label = h5("Variables:"),
                                  c("Choice A" = "varone",
                                    "Choice B" = "vartwo",
                                    "Choice C" = "varthree"))),#close column
        column(10, plotlyOutput("plot"))
      )))))


 server <- function(input, output) { 
 output$plot <- renderPlotly({
 plot_ly(x = mydataset$date, y = mydataset$varone, name = 'varone', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%
  add_trace(x = mydataset$date, y = mydataset$vartwo, name = 'vartwo', mode = 'lines+markers')%>%
  add_trace(x = mydataset$date, y = mydataset$varthree, name = 'varthree', mode = 'lines+markers')
  })}

 shinyApp(ui ,server)
```

Comment: maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36799857/r-shiny-to-select-traces-for-plotly-line-chart could help

Comment: "select which lines appear on the graph by selecting checkboxes" btw it's already implemented in plotly. Just click/unclick in the legend the line you want to display.

Comment: Thanks fr your responses. I know about the legend being able to select and unselect the traces. I have so many variables that I want to group them by checkbox. That's the reason why the previous answer isn't as helpful, either.

Comment: maybe you could edit your post to reflect this requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

But first I suggest you to reshape your dataset from wide to long. For each of your choice, you will be able to have them by group.

```
library(reshape2)

mydataset_long <- melt(mydataset, id.vars=c("date"))

ui <- shinyUI(
  navbarPage(theme=shinytheme("journal"), "My Dashboard",
             tabPanel("Data",
                      fluidPage(
                        fluidRow(
                          column(2, dateRangeInput("daterange1", label = h5("Date Range:"),
                                                   start = "2001-01-01",
                                                   end   = "2010-12-31"),
                                 br(),
                                 selectInput("mychoice", "Variables",
                                                    c("Choice A",
                                                      "Choice B",
                                                      "Choice C"))),#close column
                          column(10, plotlyOutput("myPlot"))
                        )))))


server <- function(input, output) { 
  output$myPlot = renderPlotly({

    if(identical(input$mychoice, "Choice A")) {
      mydataset_long_s <- mydataset_long %>% filter(variable == "varone")
      plot_ly(data=mydataset_long_s, x=~as.Date(date), y=~value, line = list(shape="linear"))
    } else {
      if(identical(input$mychoice, "Choice B")) {
        mydataset_long_s <- mydataset_long %>% filter(variable == "vartwo")
      plot_ly(data=mydataset_long_s, x=~as.Date(date), y=~value, line = list(shape="linear"))
    }  else {
        mydataset_long_s <- mydataset_long %>% filter(variable == "varthree")
        plot_ly(data=mydataset_long_s, x=~as.Date(date), y=~value, line = list(shape="linear"))
      }
    } 

})
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you! Very very helpful! To clarify- if I wanted to have "Choice A" plot both "varone" and "vartwo", how could I add "vartwo" to the filter() argument?

Comment: something like this should work: filter(variable == "varone" & variable == "vartwo") or filter(variable == "varone" | variable == "vartwo")